# What's the new assemblyinfo task in Albacore 2.0?

Tags: ruby, rake, albacore

I tried to update my build scripts using the latest version of Ruby/Rake and Albacore. Coming from

```
Ruby 2.0.0
Rake 10.1.1
Albacore 0.3.5
```

I updated the build server to

```
Ruby 2.1.6
Rake 10.4.2
Albacore 2.3.22
```

I already figured out that '`msbuild`' changed to '`build`' etc. But I failed to get a pendant or the new name of '`assemblyinfo`'. Has '`assemblyinfo`' been removed from the Albacore package? Or has it been renamed?

Here's my minimum script that fails.

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/clean'
require 'albacore'
require 'albacore/tasks/versionizer'
require 'albacore/ext/teamcity'

desc 'Create the assembly info file'
assemblyinfo :assembly_version do |cmd|
  puts "Here I am"
end
```

Error message:

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `assemblyinfo' for main:Object

Here's the list of all installed gems

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

albacore (2.3.22)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
map (6.5.5)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (4.7.5)
nokogiri (1.6.5 x86-mingw32)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.4.2, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
semver2 (3.4.2)
test-unit (2.1.6.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `asmver` task or `asmver_files` for multiple projects.

https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki/asmver-and-asmver_files